# Qt 5 use EGL backend for XCB

Tags: qt, qt5, egl, glx, xcb

I am having some tearing issues with embedded Qt 5 with the XCB backend. I have just realized that perhaps this causes it to default to GLX and I have heard that one has a far greater chance of eliminating tearing using EGL. I also know that Qt has an EGL backend for XCB but I have no idea how to switch between the two. What configuration or runtime flags can I use to force it to use the one instead of the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION` env variable to `xcb_egl`.

I don't see why this would eliminate tearing, which is instead typically created by lack of vsync, but there's that...

Comment: Ok this has no effect. I assumed that because eglfs apparently solves vsync issues for many egl on X11 might help. Do you think that eglfs with an X11 backend would make a difference? Also, how can I confirm that egl support was even compiled into XCB and that it is in fact using it?

Comment: EGLFS is an entirely different thing, that doesn't use X11 at all (Qt opens `/dev/fb0` or similar and uses EGL to create OpenGL contextes over that). To be sure of what's happening, enable some debugging logging for the `qt.xcb.glintegration` category (aka set `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt.xcb.*=true"` and run your application).

Comment: Hi yes I know EGLFS is very different but I know that there is an X11 backend as opposed to the standard KMS one for it even though it is mainly meant for development but I can't get that working. I am not seeing any logging output, is it being written to a file or do I need to set something else to see it?

Comment: Ok the X11 backend on EGLFS behaves the same. I guess EGL isn't the solution then...

Comment: Do you have vsync enabled or not? That's the big thing.

Comment: Yes I believe I do because now that I have EGLFS I can force it to be off and that makes things worse. I'm not sure if there is a xorg setting for it though. It does only tear when I am animating more than one item at a time in qml. I'm guessing this could be a qml vsync issue?